# Having the Stomach Flu and Eating Pasta With Cheese?

Tags: nutrition

I've heard eating dairy is one of the worst possible things to do when one has the stomach flu, but is it a quantity or substance issue? If someone ate a lot of pasta with a lot of shredded parmesan cheese on top, would that cause a significant intestinal upset? I'm wondering if it's, as said, bad to only eat the cheese, or if it won't be too bad if it's displaced significantly by another healthier substance.

Comment: I presume that by "stomach flu" you mean short-term nausea and perhaps vomiting that's usually caused by food poisoning or viral infections such as novovirus. Is that what you mean? If so, I'm a bit puzzled how someone with such an illness would want to (or even be able to) eat a plate of pasta at all, with or without cheese.

Comment: Not food poisoning, the other kind. It's more of an after-effect thing where, after eating nothing but crackers and other incredibly bland food, the appetite has returned while the virus is still fairly active. It's the recovery period where one wants a fuller meal, but it's still a bad idea to just drink plain milk (as an example). I'm just wondering how a little bit of cheese would effect the individual at this point in the infection.

Comment: Caffeine, fatty foods and diary. Those are the three to avoid, to ensure a good recovery :-)

Comment: So it's a substance issue rather than quantity? Just avoid any amount of dairy?

Comment: Hmm, sort of. A very small amount would go unnoticed but, a large amount would not (visually). There's fat in mostly all foods, just not as much as you would find in dairy. It's difficult to describe, to be honest. And I'd be culled if I were to answer in the comments. Unless it would be a very small amount, I'd stay away from it, considering that you're stomach will be very sensitive at this moment in time. A small sprinkle of cheese wouldn't harm you, however.

Comment: @user19679 - By this forum's standards you already have answered in comments. I think the fact that this conversation hasn't been deleted is because they're short one moderator currently. I recommend moving your comments to a proper answer.

Comment: @Ray25Lee - There's really no easy way for you to know whether "stomach flu" is a food-borne illness or viral, so saying "not food poisoning" isn't really accurate.